# How to get unique indexes of a sorted Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that I need to sort but I need to get the indexes of the sorted items too. The ArrayList often has many duplicate values as it is updated and the indexex I get are duplicate. I need the unique indexes. Is there a way to get those indexes?

```
indices = new int[depth.size()];
ArrayList<Float> fStore = new ArrayList(depth);
Collections.sort(depth); 
for (int n=0; n<depth.size(); n++){      
  indices[n] = fStore.indexOf(depth.get(n));      
}
```

Comment: 1. you don't show your objects; 2. there is no such thing as an "index" in Java. Please show some code.

Comment: @fge "2. there is no such thing as an "index" in Java" - ????

Comment: Post an example list, what output you want to get, and what you have tried already.

Comment: All the elements will be having a unique index, the fact that you are getting the same value is that, you are requesting the index of same variable again and again!

Comment: @brso05 well, that's the truth; what is so surprising?

Comment: What is a duplicate index?

Comment: @fge it's not the truth `int[] a = new int[5];`   `a[0]` `0` IS AN INDEX...

Comment: @fge What do you mean, "no such thing as an index"?

Comment: Technically in a Java ArrayList, each entry has one and only one "index", which is its position in the list. If you are talking about something else, please develop. Maybe you need to use another data structure like a SortedMap.

Comment: @brso05 in the list, yes; pertaining to the elements of the list, no

Comment: @khelwood see my comment above

Comment: @fge so don't say `there is no such thing as an "index" in java`

Comment: @fge I can create a class that has index as a property and put a bunch of objects in an `ArrayList` so each element will have an `index` property...

Comment: [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-java)

Comment: @brso05 it is true nevertheless; it just happens that there is an interface in Java, `List`, which has a `.get()` method whose argument is an `int` and this argument is called an "index"; fundamentally, my statement holds true: there is no such thing as an index in Java (except for arrays)

Comment: @fge a `List` index and an `Array` index are fundamentally the same thing...

Comment: @fge the underlying data structure of an `ArrayList` is an `Array`...

Comment: @brso05 _because of the implementation_; a `List` has no guarantee _at all_ that the underlying data structure is an array

Comment: @fge when you pass an `int` to the `get()` method the method is going to the underlying array and using that `int` as the `index` of the underlying array.

Comment: @fge I didn't say `List` I said `ArrayList`.

Comment: @brso05 read my comment above; there is no such guarantee; it is just a contract, and it just happens that the argument is called the _index_. And that is all there is to it

Comment: @fge read my comment above there is a guarantee that an `ArrayList` has an array as the underlying data structure...`ARRAYList` there are `indexes` in `Java` all over the place and it doesn't `"just happen to be called index"` it is called `index` because it's and `index` and that is all there is too it!

Comment: @fge http://stackoverflow.com/a/3467975/4028085

Comment: @fge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array

Comment: @fge http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaDatastructureList/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `indexOf()` is that it returns the index of the **first occurrence** of the element in the list, or `-1` if not present. If your list has duplicates, then, for these duplicates, you'll get the index of their first occurrence within the list.

There are many ways to accomplish what you want. One is to use a `SortedSet` and a helper `IndexedEntry` class:

```
public class IndexedEntry<T extends Comparable<T>>
    implements Comparable<IndexedEntry<T>> {

    private final Integer index;

    private final T entry;

    public IndexedEntry(Integer index, T entry) {
        this.index = index;
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }

    public T getEntry() {
        return this.entry;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(IndexedEntry<T> other) {
        int byEntry = this.getEntry().compareTo(other.getEntry());
        if (byEntry == 0) {
            return this.getIndex().compareTo(other.getIndex());
        }
        return byEntry;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.entry + ", " + this.index + ")";
    }
}
```

The `IndexedEntry` class simply wraps a `Comparable` value and its index, and implements `Comparable` by first comparing the value, and if the value is equal, then it compares the index. This means that an ordered list of `IndexedEntry` will have its elements ordered by `(value, index)`.

To use the `IndexedEntry` class, just iterate over your collection, create an `IndexedEntry` for each element by wrapping the element and its index, and then sort the list of `IndexedEntry`:

```
    List<Float> unordered = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3.2f, 1.0f, 7.5f, 3.2f, 0.8f));
    System.out.println(unordered); // [3.2, 1.0, 7.5, 3.2, 0.8]

    List<IndexedEntry<Float>> ordered = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < unordered.size(); i++) {
        IndexedEntry<Float> entry = new IndexedEntry<>(i, unordered.get(i));
        ordered.add(entry);
    }
    Collections.sort(ordered);
    System.out.println(ordered); // [(0.8, 4), (1.0, 1), (3.2, 0), (3.2, 3), (7.5, 2)]
```

Once sorted, the `ordered` list will contain the elements along with the original index.