# How we can write any collection program with out import java.util.*;

Tags: java

How we can write any collection program in java  with out using  (import java.util.*; ) package

Comment: You can't, since the Collection class is in the Java Util package. [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Comment: Or do you want to re invent the wheel by rewriting the Collection class?

Comment: Why would you want to do it unless you want to write your own implementation of Collection from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How we can write any collection program in java with out using (import java.util.*; ) package?

We can use the fully qualified class name [`java.util.Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), `import` is a convenience for developer typing.

```
java.util.Collection<String> c = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the required functionality such as add new item, delete item etc, we can write an user defined collection program with the help of array values.

In Java collections, the values will be stored in an array to the certain defined amount. If that array is filled completely with the values to the defined amount then the new array will be created to the larger size more than the current array size and all the values from the previous array will be copied to the newly created array.

Source: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13387404/4067157) & [Open Source for geeks](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/05/interview-question-10-how-arraylist.html)