# How to index a line of text in Java?

Tags: java, decoder

I'm very new to the Java language, and in one of my school assignments, they want us to take in a simple text file that contains a line of text and index it (so that it can be used as a decoder for a secret message). I already know how to read the file and get that line of text into the program, but how do I index each character in the line of text and assign each character a value starting at 0 and ending at the length of the line of text? Here is what I have so far (*Note: I was trying different stuff with the code in the for loop, so I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Decoder 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName;

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of a file to be decoded: ");
    fileName = keyboard.nextLine();

    File testFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(testFile);

    String keyPhrase = inputFile.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < keyPhrase.length(); i++)
    {
        char letter = keyPhrase.charAt(i);
        int num = (int)letter;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your sample input and the desired output pls?

Comment: You must store the values in an array, such as `array[i] = letter` during your loop. This documentation by Oracle should really help you solve this problem - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Adding characters to a list would be "better" than an array.

Comment: @BevynQ The length of the `keyPhrase` String is known in advance. Practically, a fixed dimension array has performance advantage over the dynamically sizable List which is fundamentally constructed from an array anyway. When a bigger array is needed by the List, it reallocates the array size and copies over the elements from the old array when necessary. It's really not "better' when you already know the size needed. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3467975/1161948

Comment: premature optimisation is the root of all evil.